# Spring Aspect to log exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop

I added aspect like below in my spring-boot REST API to log calls to all methods in package "com.leanring.sprint" like so:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAdvice {
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogAdvice.class);
    
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.learning.spring.*.*.*(..))")
    public void pointCut() {
        
    }

    @Around("pointCut()")
    public Object appLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        String className = jp.getTarget().getClass().toString();
        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();  
    
        logger.info("Start call: " + className + ":" + methodName + "()" + " with arguments: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(args));
        
        Object object = jp.proceed();
        
        logger.info("End call: " + className + ":" + methodName + "()" + " returned: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(object));
                
        return object;
    }
}
```

This is working fine, but I would also like it to be able to log any exceptions that could occur when a method is called.

How do I do that?

Comment: why not use `@AfterThrowing` advice?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could add another `@AfterThrowing` advice using the same pointcut or wrap `jp.proceed();` inside a try-catch block.

Comment: Exactly. You use `@AfterThrowing` if you do not need to handle the exceptions, just log them. If you want to handle (a subset of) the exceptions, you need to use `@Around`.